# Host a PHP website a Amazon webservice EC2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

How i can host my php website at EC2. I have brand new account at amazon web serive. Some one let me know about the setup of configure this.

Thanks,
Pradeep

Comment: should be a serverfault question. You may try Google, (many) answers is already there.

Answer (score 4):

As Dan mentioned, there is no difference between a server on Amazon EC2 and any other server. I suppose you are looking for a way to get started.

Start from this article - [How To: Getting Started with Amazon EC2](http://paulstamatiou.com/how-to-getting-started-with-amazon-ec2)

You'll now have a running server with root access. You can now do a default server installation. For example, assuming you'll be installing Ubuntu, read [this article](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-natty-narwhal-ubuntu-11.04-ispconfig-2).

Search google for any specific problems or features (such as need for static IP) and if everything else fails, ask here.

Hope this helps you to get started.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between hosting a site on EC2 and hosting one on a server anywhere else. Install Apache and PHP. On a CentOS server (there are many CentOS images in the AMI library), "yum install httpd", "yum install php", set up your virtual host and upload your site. That's it.